# Bayonetta: Switch Weapons (L2)

Tags: bayonetta

What is the purpose of switch weapons? I notice that when she's running around she'll have a sword or guns, but haven't seen her attack with the sword when it looks like it is equipped. Could someone explain this mechanic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is referenced elsewhere but not called out explicitly: you can organize the weapons Bayonetta uses with her hands and feet into two pairs, between which "switch weapons" will switch. The weapon select menu is kind of messy so it's possible to miss this. Certain weapons can only be used with one of the two appendages (eg: Odette), and certain weapons can only be used on the feet once an upgrade has been purchased. Being able to quickly switch between weapons isn't always useful but it has at least two benefits:

1. Certain weapons have contextual
   drawbacks. For example, equipping
   the [Odette](http://bayonetta.wikia.com/wiki/Odette) increases your
   motion speed, but it also introduces
   a delay in your motions, which
   prevents you from stopping or
   turning quickly. This is fine in
   large open spaces, but not so useful
   when platforming or jumping. Being
   able to switch between the Odette
   and, say, the [Onyx Roses](http://bayonetta.wikia.com/wiki/Onyx_Roses) would
   be very helpful.
2. switching weapons mid-combo can
   result in even awesomer combos.

Comment: thanks, i hadnt gotten any of the new weapons yet so thats where my confusion was. i saw that switching to kilgore for a PPP-K during the - will create a pretty amazing combo

Comment: yeah, and even after playing quite a bit of the game I found out that I had missed a bunch of weapons so if you're interested in getting some of the unique ones on the first pass - make sure to look them up!

Comment: yeah, still planning on hitting it up on hard mode, or easy, just to play it; gotta love the playability of hack 'n slashers

Answer (score 2):

Switching weapons *should* make it so you're attacking with those weapons. For example, if you have the Flaming Durgas or the Kulshedra, when you switch to those weapons, you should then be attacking with those instead of the guns. It can sometimes be advantageous to switch weapons during combat in order to increase your combo. If you're hitting <kbd>L2</kbd> twice really quickly, then you might possibly be switching to the alternate weapon then switching back to the guns before you're able to use the alternate weapon, which might explain why you haven't seen her attack with it.